# Path to file(image) in Notification Service Extension folder

Tags: ios, objective-c, attachment, unnotificationserviceextension, unnotificationattachment

I am trying to add a local image(icon) as an attachment to a remote notification on iOS 12. In other words the image URL is not passed in the notification userInfo but is determined internally based on other criteria in userInfo. Therefore I want a library of icons bundled with the app to choose from. I can't determine what the relative URL would be if I wanted to add an image of this kind to the notification. This is what I'm trying to do, and the "example.png" file is in the "Notification Service Extension" folder.

I want to know how to copy over a folder of images from xcode to the device I'm building to.

Then I want to know what the relative path would be to access these images to use for the attachments.

```
UNMutableNotificationContent *content = [UNMutableNotificationContent new];
content.title = @"Title";
content.body = @"Body";
content.sound = [UNNotificationSound defaultSound];
NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"example.png"];
NSError *error;
UNNotificationAttachment *icon = [UNNotificationAttachment attachmentWithIdentifier:@"image" URL:imageURL options:nil error:&error];
if (error)
{
    NSLog(@"error while storing image attachment in notification: %@", error);
}
if (icon)
{
    content.attachments = @[icon];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just copy the directory of images to your Xcode project. Xcode will *bundle* it and copy it to the device. On the device, do the following (taken directly from the docs)

```
NSBundle *main = [NSBundle mainBundle];
NSString *resourcePath = [main pathForResource:@"Seagull" ofType:@"jpg"];
```

That from the docs, but there is also a `URLForResource:withExtention` which is better to use.

Comment: I used `URLForResource:withExtention` and it worked. I suspect that the `pathForResource:ofType` method did not provide the proper escaping to create a URL.

Comment: Great stuff ... yes that is the better alternative ..